# Send messages from multiple SNS topics to a single Amazon SQS

Tags: yaml, terraform, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, terragrunt

New to Terraform!

I am trying to send messages from two SNS topics `SNSA` and `SNSB` to an Amazon `SQS`
everything is good when i do a `plz plan` in my local and "then" i try to deploy through JENKINS which gives me an error saying:

```
Error: error creating SNS topic subscription: AuthorizationError: User: arn:aws:sts::325400131687:assumed-role/JENKINSDEPLOY/ is not authorized to perform: 
SNS:Subscribe on resource: arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:snsb
```

**Interesting thing here is SNSA doesn't have this problem**
and i get an output saying `aws_sns_topic_subscription.snsa: Creation complete after 1s`

I gave same permissions to both the SNSs, My two cents is on the `Roles/Perms` which i think i messed up!!
Because when i try to re-order the SNS topics in my `MsgPerm.yml` (placing SNSB first followed by SNSA) this time SNSB gets created and got the same error for SNSA

**Any suggestions or comments related to this issue, will be appreciated, thanks**

my roles and permissions are setup as below:

`MsgPerm.yml`

```
---
statements:
  -
    effect: "Allow"
    actions:
      - "sqs:AddPermission"
      - "sqs:CreateQueue"
      - "sqs:DeleteQueue"
      - "sqs:Get*"
      - "sqs:List*"
      - "sqs:PurgeQueue"
      - "sqs:RemovePermission"
      - "sqs:SetQueueAttributes"
      - "sqs:TagQueue"
      - "sqs:UnTagQueue"
    resources:
      - !Sub "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:myproject*"
  -
    effect: "Allow"
    actions:
      - "sqs:SendMessage"
      - "sqs:SendMessageBatch"
      - "sqs:ReceiveMessage"
      - "sqs:DeleteMessage"
      - "sqs:DeleteMessageBatch"
      - "sqs:DeleteQueue"
      - "sqs:CreateQueue"
      - "sqs:AddPermission"
      - "sqs:PurgeQueue"
      - "sqs:RemovePermission"
      - "sqs:TagQueue"
      - "sqs:UntagQueue"
      - "sqs:Set*"
      - "sqs:Get*"
      - "sqs:List*"
    resources:
      - !Sub "arn:aws:sqs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:myproject*"
      - "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:snsa"
      - "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:snsb"
  -
    effect: "Allow"
    actions:
      - "sns:CreateTopic"
      - "sns:DeleteTopic"
      - "sns:Subscribe"
      - "sns:Unsubscribe"
      - "sns:AddPermission"
      - "sns:RemovePermission"
      - "sns:Receive"
      - "sns:Publish"
      - "sns:TagResource"
      - "sns:UntagResource"
      - "sns:Set*"
      - "sns:Get*"
      - "sns:List*"
    resources:
      - !Sub "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:PREFIX*"
      - "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:snsa"
      - "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:snsb"
```

`JENKINSDEPLOY.yml`

```
---
managedPolicyArns:
  -
    name: Enterprise/GoldenVPCRequirements
    cignamanaged: true
  -
    name: AmazonAPIGatewayAdministrator
    awsmanaged: true
  -
    name: MsgPerm
    awsmanaged: false
  -
    name: SecurityPerm
    awsmanaged: false

federated: true
```

and finally my `sns.tf` file

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "snsa" {
  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:${var.datastore_account_region}:${var.datastore_account_id}:${var.sns_topic_snsa}"
  protocol  = "sqs"
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.incoming.arn

  depends_on = [
    aws_sqs_queue.incoming
  ]
}


resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "snsb" {
  topic_arn = "arn:aws:sns:${var.datastore_account_region}:${var.datastore_account_id}:${var.sns_topic_snsb}"
  protocol  = "sqs"
  endpoint  = aws_sqs_queue.incoming.arn

  depends_on = [
    aws_sqs_queue.incoming
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello , can you tell me how you could solve this problem?

I currently have the same to be able to subscribe to my topic

Answer (score 0):

Your error message writes:

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:SNSB
```

but your policy uses (different case `snsb`):

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:453101592424:snsb
```

Topic names are **case sensitive**.

Comment: yes i know, snsa and snsb - those are made up names and its a typo in my question, i've updated it now, thanks